Get field from Apache Spark Row which is Wrapped array as a Seq into a List using Scala
Background

Fetching data in json format from delta table
Using Apache Spark and Scala

DATA FORMAT
  val factories = """
      {
        "cities": {
          "name": "Sao Paulo"
          "areas": [
            {
              "code": "41939",
              "type": "downtown"
            },
            {
              "code": "48294",
              "type": "residential"
            }
          ],
        },
       
        "domains": [
            {
               "id": "19sk2nfb",
               "name" : "defense"
            }
        ]
    }

CODE
This fetches the data from the delta table and creates case class objects
fetchedData is DataFrame fetched using some criteria
factoriesSchema is json schema
val structuredData =
    fetchedData.withColumn(
      "StructuredFactoryJson",
      from_json(col("FactoryData"), factoriesSchema)
  )

val factories = structuredData.collect().map { row =>
      val structJson = row.getAs[Row]("StructuredFactoryJson")
      val citiesRow = structJson.getAs[Row]("cities")
      val city = City(
        citiesRow.getAs[String]("name"),
        citiesRow
          .getAs[Seq[Row]]("areas")
          .map(areaRow =>
            Area(
              area.getAs[String]("type"),
              area.getAs[String]("code")
            )
          )
      )
      val domains = structJson
        .getAs[Seq[Row]]("domains")
        .map( area ->
           Area( area.getAs
             .
             .
             .

    }



Problem
This works fine and Seq is obtained. But the issues is that, if there is any way to get List instead of Seq and construct the bigger object as is

it seems like you want to just call .toList afterwards, but is there a reason you can't change whatever class there is to use the more general Seq anyway?

There is a program which generated the models and it is using List for immutability, hence the questions. Did not find any trivial way to achieve this within given constraints of fetching from the Row and at the same time converting to case class object

After digging around a bit I found 2 ways to accomplish this

Using JavaConverters

This approach was first discovered in an attempt to get a List from the instead of Seq. But it was observed that the List returned is a Java List. Hence it was needed to convert it to Scala List
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val factories = structuredData.collect().map { row =>
      val structJson = row.getAs[Row]("StructuredFactoryJson")
      val citiesRow = structJson.getAs[Row]("cities")
      val city = City(
        citiesRow.getAs[String]("name"),
        citiesRow
          .getList(citiesRow.fieldIndex("areas"))
          .asScala
          .map((areaRow : Row) =>
            Area(
              areaRow.getAs[String]("type"),
              areaRow.getAs[String]("code")
            )
          ).toList
      )
      val domains = structJson
        .getList(structJson.fieldIndex("domains"))
        .asScala
        .map((area : Row) ->
           Area( area.getAs
             .
             .
             .
       ).toList
    }

Issues

Version and package : The details about JavaConverters version and packages can be found in this SO Question

There can be performance issues while converting lists



Without JavaConverters

Again doing some more search I found the more descent approach and settled with this one
val factories = structuredData.collect().map { row =>
      val structJson = row.getAs[Row]("StructuredFactoryJson")
      val citiesRow = structJson.getAs[Row]("cities")
      val city = City(
        citiesRow.getAs[String]("name"),
        citiesRow
          .getSeq[Row](citiesRow.fieldIndex("areas"))
          .map((areaRow : Row) =>
            Area(
              areaRow.getAs[String]("type"),
              areaRow.getAs[String]("code")
            )
          ).toList
      )
      val domains = structJson
        .getSeq[Row](structJson.fieldIndex("domains"))
        .asScala
        .map((area : Row) ->
           Area( area.getAs
             .
             .
             .
       ).toList
    }

This resolved the issue

Given the requirement of a pre-existing class to encode it would seem sparkutils frameless could be best suited as it supports List out of the box.
It's based on the excellent frameless library with some extra changes present (including List support).
To use it you must make sure you don't include the SparkSession implicits as you'd typically do.  see here for examples.

I don't quite fully understand but seems too much for issue that can be solved with native language support
